# getting parent attribute from a known child's value

Tags: xml, xpath

Trying to select an element's attriibute based on the value of one or more of it's children, no matter how deep.

Thinking of the following but not working, appreciate any help, thanks !

```
"//*[node()[contains(text(), 'FirstInfo')] and node()[contains(text(), 'SecondInfo')]/::parent]"
```

this is the XML:

```
<root>
<a ID="GetThisText">
  <b>
   <c>FirstInfo</c>

   <d>SecondInfo</d>
</b>
</a>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
'//*[contains(., "FirstInfo")][contains(., "SecondInfo")]/ancestor::*/@ID'
```

or better :

```
'//*[c="FirstInfo" and d="SecondInfo"]/ancestor::a/@ID'
```

Comment: and then, i did : if(!empty($result)){
                
                      echo $result[0][@ID];
 
                   } to test the result, to no avail. meaning it failed ?

Comment: This is correct XPath, but I don't think it matches the question exactly: "...based on the value of one or more of it's children, no matter how deep". Therefore, you'd have to use `descendant::` or `ancestor`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following path expression

```
//a[descendant::c = 'FirstInfo' and descendant::d = 'SecondInfo']/@ID
```

which translates to

```
//a                                  Find all elements `a` no matter where in the XML
                                     tree
[descendant::c = 'FirstInfo'         But only return them if they have a descendant
                                     element 'c' with the value "FirstInfo"
and descendant::d = 'SecondInfo']    and a descendant element "d" with the value
                                     "SecondInfo"
/@ID                                 of those elements `a` return the element `ID`.
```

and results in

```
ID="GetThisText"
```

Comment: @sputnick.. koooool ! it worked. and i learnt a lot. thanks man !